# log4j:ERROR Failed to load driver java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j

I am on OSX Yosmite and JRE8, I dont get to seem to get the logging to database to work with log4j, does anyone have a solution for this?

log4j:ERROR Failed to load driver

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.setDriver(JDBCAppender.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.getConnection(JDBCAppender.java:248)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:215)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:186)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:322)
```

Comment: this is part of the log4 jar file which is not modifiable : log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender, unless you can recommend me a different appender for MySQL?

Comment: The ODBC Bridge is gone in Java 8. Use a real JDBC driver instead.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors with log4j using either "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" or "org.postgresql.Driver". Is there a real JDBC driver to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, You cannot use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge because it has been removed. Need to replace your logging jar with `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar`